# Data from a DataGridView Configured on Another Form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have Form1 that has a dataGridView and a button to add contents to that Grid. When selecting this button, I call Form2 which has 2 TextBox and a ComboBox to populate the Name, Directory and Format (for example), plus an OK button to add the row to the dataGridView on Form1.

When I get back on Form1, the dataGridView must be showing the content entered. What happens is that my Grid has three columns: Name, Format and a button column to, when clicking it, reload that screen of Form2 with the previously filled information loaded again in each field to be able to change or just consult.

Firstly I tried to create a function to add the lines to my Grid by parameters, as shown in the code below:

Eu tenho o Form1 que possui uma dataGridView e um botão para adicionar conteúdos nessa Grid. Ao selecionar esse botão, eu chamo o Form2 que possui 2 TextBox e um ComboBox para preencher o Nome, Diretório e Formato (por exemplo), além de um botão OK para adicionar a linha a dataGridView na Form1.

Form 1

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void AddRows(string name, string path)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(name, path);
    dataGridView1.Update();
}
```

Form 2

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nome = txt_name.Text;
    var path = txt_path.Text;

    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.AddRows(name, path);
}
```

However, it ended up not working, showing nothing on the Grid. So I thought about creating a class with a name, path and format method (get and set for each) to store everything in a list of objects (I think that's it, forgive me if I'm wrong because I'm a beginner). Or save to a DataSet. But then I thought, I instantiate the class in my Form2 and pass the values filled in the fields, but then, what do I do in my Form1?

I think it's all very confusing, I'd appreciate it if someone could explain a clearer method of resolving this situation and please be very specific since I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve. It appears you have two forms. On form (form1) there is a `DataGridView` and a `Button` to add new rows to the grid. On the second form (form2) there are two text boxes and a combo box and a button for “OK”. I am guessing the text boxes are used to allow the user to enter a new “Name” and “Format” data. Then, when the user clicks the “OK” button, the data in the text boxes are added to a new row of the `DataGridView` in form1. Finally, the “Edit” button on each row of the `DataGridView` allows the user to open the SAME form2 (used to add new items) and use it to edit the row the user clicked.

I hope I understand this correctly. This is doable and there are many ways to achieve this. I can only assume there is SOME reason you would not simply “add” or “edit” these cells directly in the grid. The default behavior of the `DataGridView` to “add new rows” or “edit cells” is already implemented and there is no need for a form2 to do this when you can achieve the same thing without a new form2 and absolutely no code is needed. Therefore, I will assume there is a reason you can not edit the cells directly in the grid. Having a `DataSource` could be a reason (see below)…

The answer below is ONE way to achieve this. I must give a warning if there is a `DataSource` with the `DataGridView`. You can use this approach however, whenever the code below adds or edits cells in the grid, it does so by directly accessing the grids cells. This will NOT work if there is a `DataSource` attached to the grid. If there is a `DataSource`, then when the code below adds or edits items, you would need to change the code to do these add/edit operations to the `DataSource` and NOT the grid itself.

Most of the work can be done in `Form2`. In both an “Add” or “Edit” situation `Form2` is going to need at least ONE item from `Form1`… that would be `Form1`’s `DataGridView`. Using the “Add” method as an example, it is going to need `Form1`’s `DataGridView` in order to add a new row. This can be achieved by simply creating a new constructor for `Form2` that takes a `DataGridView` in its signature. The code below is how you would call this new constructor from `Form1`’s `btnAdd_Click` event.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Form2 f2 = new Form2(dataGridView1);
  f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Now we need to make this constructor in `Form2`. Since the new row will not be added until the user presses the “Add/OK” button, we need to save `Fom1`’s `DataGridView` passed in by the constructor. Therefore a global `DataGridView` variable `parentDGV` is created. When the constructor is called we simply need to set `parentDGV` to the passed in `DataGridView`. This will allow access to the grid in the “Add” method.

```
DataGridView parentDGV;

public Form2(DataGridView dgv) {
  parentDGV = dgv;
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

Since we now have access to `Form1`’s `DataGridView` you could simply add the new row. No error checking is done so the text boxes may be empty. Below is `Form2`’s “Add” button click event.

```
private void btnAddToGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  parentDGV.Rows.Add(txtName.Text, txtFormat.Text);
}
```

This should allow the user to add a new row of data in `Form1`’s `DataGridView` from `Form2`’s “Add” button.

Next, we need to take care of the “Edit” buttons on each row of the `DataGridView`. If you want to use the same `Form2` to edit rows, then you will need to make some changes since it currently will only add rows. To make `Form2` work properly, it will need to know if the user clicked the “Edit” or “Add” button on `Form1`. One way to achieve this is to make another constructor for `Form2`. This constructor will obviously need `Form1`’s `DataGridView`, but also it will need a “Row” index of the “Edit” button clicked. This will give us the row index of the row to edit. We can make a global `int` variable “editRowIndex” to allow access from other methods in `Form2`.

```
DataGridView parentDGV;
int editRowIndex;

public Form2(DataGridView dgv, int rowIndex) {
  parentDGV = dgv;
  editRowIndex = rowIndex;
  InitializeComponent();
  SetEditForm();
}
```

The `SetEditForm` method makes some cosmetic changes to the form by filling the text boxes with the data to edit, changes the “Add” button text to “Update” and more importantly, changes the buttons “Click” event handler to update the row in the grid instead of adding a new row.

```
private void SetEditForm() {
  btnAddToGrid.Text = "Update";
  this.btnAddToGrid.Click -= this.btnAddToGrid_Click;
  this.btnAddToGrid.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnAddToGrid_EditClick);
  if (parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["AName"].Value != null)
    txtName.Text = parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["AName"].Value.ToString();
  else
    txtName.Text = "";

  if (parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["Format"].Value != null)
    txtFormat.Text = parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["Format"].Value.ToString();
  else
    txtFormat.Text = "";
  // set combo box value
}
```

Below is the `EditClick` event to update the proper row in the grid with the new data from `Form2` text boxes. I assume once the user is done editing, the form would close.

```
private void btnAddToGrid_EditClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["AName"].Value = txtName.Text;
  parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["Format"].Value = txtFormat.Text;
  this.Close();
}
```

Finally, the last part to take care of is when the user clicks an “Edit” button, on one of the rows in `Form1`’s `DataGridview`. To handle this the `DataGridView`’s `CellClick` event is wired up. Once the clicked cell is determined to be the “Edit” button, we simply create the new `Form2` with the proper constructor.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if ((e.RowIndex >= 0) && (!dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) ) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0) {
      if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Edit") {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(dataGridView1, e.RowIndex);
        f2.ShowDialog();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense. Putting it all together… Using the “Designer”… `Form1` has a `DataGridView` with two text box columns (AName, Format) and a third button column (Edit) to edit the row via `Form2`. Also, `Form1` has a button to “Add” a new row via `Form2`

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FillGrid();
}

private void FillGrid() {
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Cell00Data", "Cell01Data");
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Cell10Data", "Cell11Data");
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Cell20Data", "Cell21Data");
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Cell30Data", "Cell31Data");
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Form2 f2 = new Form2(dataGridView1);
  f2.ShowDialog();
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if ((e.RowIndex >= 0) && (!dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) ) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0) {
      if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Edit") {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(dataGridView1, e.RowIndex);
        f2.ShowDialog();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Form2: Using the ‘Designer, `Form2` has two text boxes (`txtName`, `txtFormat`) for “Name” and “Format”, a `Button` to either “Add” the info as a new item or “Update” a row in the grid.

```
DataGridView parentDGV;
int editRowIndex;

// Constructor to Add a new row
public Form2(DataGridView dgv) {
  parentDGV = dgv;
  InitializeComponent();
}
// Constructor to Edit a row
public Form2(DataGridView dgv, int rowIndex) {
  parentDGV = dgv;
  editRowIndex = rowIndex;
  InitializeComponent();
  SetEditForm();
}
// update form for edit mode
private void SetEditForm() {
  btnAddToGrid.Text = "Update";
  this.btnAddToGrid.Click -= this.btnAddToGrid_Click;
  this.btnAddToGrid.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnAddToGrid_EditClick);
  if (parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["AName"].Value != null)
    txtName.Text = parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["AName"].Value.ToString();
  else
    txtName.Text = "";

  if (parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["Format"].Value != null)
    txtFormat.Text = parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["Format"].Value.ToString();
  else
    txtFormat.Text = "";
  // set combo box value
}

// Button click event to update form1’s grid
private void btnAddToGrid_EditClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["AName"].Value = txtName.Text;
  parentDGV.Rows[editRowIndex].Cells["Format"].Value = txtFormat.Text;
  this.Close();
}

// Button click event to add a row to form1’s grid
private void btnAddToGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  parentDGV.Rows.Add(txtName.Text, txtFormat.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try my demo?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //change code to get current row and check null, etc 
        var sels = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
        if (sels == null || sels.Count == 0)
            return;
        DataGridViewRow selRow = sels[0];
        frmDialog dlg = new frmDialog(
            selRow.Cells[0].Value,
            selRow.Cells[1].Value);
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selRow.Cells[0].Value = dlg.Col1Value;
            selRow.Cells[1].Value = dlg.Col2Value;
            //...
        }
    }
}

    public partial class frmDialog : Form
{
    public object Col1Value;
    public object Col2Value;
    //...other properties
    public frmDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public frmDialog(object col1, object col2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Col1Value = col1;
        this.Col2Value = col2;
        //...other properties
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to this problem is to use a modal dialog and tag/pass the information through to a list in Form1.

```
        frmNewConfig f = new frmNewConfig();
        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Object c = new Object();
            c = (Object)f.Tag;
            _yourList.Add(c);
          **example**
             valueA = txtValueA.Text;
             valueB = txtValueB.Text;
        }
```

Now in Form1 you should have a means of binding your list to a DGV such as:

```
yourDGV.DataSource = typeof(Object); 
   //OR
yourDGV.DataSource = yourList;
```

Don't forget to create an instance of the list in your frmLoad before trying to assign objects to it.